# In MySQL does a UNIQUE varchar have to be a PRIMARY KEY as well?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 unique values under 1 table in MySQL.

```
|id (PK)|varchar(255) UNIQUE|
-----------------------------
|   1   |      1234abcde    |
|   2   |      5678fghij    |
|   3   |      9012klmno    |
```

Do I have to set UNIQUE varchar as a PK or I can still use auto_incremented id (int)? Is this a good or bad practice?

Comment: `UNIQUE` is just fine, no need for a primary key

Comment: You may only have one primary key in a table.

Comment: Let's say I do want a primary key for unique varchar, will that affect my performance? if yes, how can I measure it?

Comment: I believe using a varchar as a primary key must be slightly slower than an int column (assuming longer strings - the compares would have to be more expensive) - I strongly doubt that this would be your bottleneck though unless you expect a huge amount of data and high volumes of access / processing.

Comment: No, it's the other way around. A primary key must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not need to be a primary key.

Additionally: you cannot have more than one 'primary key' (different than compound primary keys), and it frequently makes sense to have an auto-increment id field for convention alone and for some frameworks (e.g. ORM's like Hibernate and Entity Framework).

To answer your second question, there are many business cases where you many enforce a unique constraint on multiple columns without making them your primary key - for example they may have to be unique, but you may need to be able to edit/change them:

i.e.

1. Email addresses for usernames - forced unique, but users will likely need to update them
2. Password salts (if your generation is sound this is unlikely to require enforcement)
3. random strings used to generate one-time or time sensitive links (think bit.ly)

So, the point being this is done all the time.

Answer (score 6):

No, it doesn't have to be a primary. Primaries are unique, but not every unique is a primary.

Answer (score 2):

One table can have multiple keys. One of them is "primary" (PRIMARY KEY) and the rest are "alternate" (UNIQUE constraint).

But beware that under InnoDB primary key also acts as a [clustered index](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/), so choosing one key or another to be primary can have profound performance implications.

Comment: +1 for InnoDB pk used for cluster, didn't know that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to. If you want to ensure uniqueness in your `varchar` column, set a unique constraint, but that doesn't mean you need to make it a PK. You can still use a numerical auto incremented id as your primary key.

This types of numerical primary keys which have no real world value are known as [surrogate keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), and their use is recommended, specially when there are much more searching in the table than insert. They can be really helpful to speed up the query performance, specially during join and searching.